# why does postgres set_config's is_local = true not persist the variable for the whole transaction?

Tags: postgresql, variables, session, transactions, plpgsql

I have a function that uses `set_config` with `is_local = true` to set a variable.
Now I expected that a select statement using the variable with `current_settings` within the same transaction would be able to access the variable, because the docs state:

> set_config(setting_name, new_value, is_local) ... set parameter and
> return new value
>
> set_config sets the parameter setting_name to new_value. If is_local
> is true, the new value will only apply to the current transaction.

But that doesn't work in my case and I get

```
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "auth.tenant_id"
SQL state: 42704
```

Any ideas where I am wrong here?

This is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auth.authorize(IN a_user_id uuid)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    SECURITY DEFINER 
AS $BODY$
declare
v_tenant_id uuid;
v_user_role auth.user_role;
begin
select tenant_id, user_role into strict v_tenant_id, v_user_role from auth.authorizations where user_id = a_user_id;
perform set_config('auth.tenant_id', v_tenant_id::text, true);
perform set_config('auth.user_role', v_user_role::text, true);
return true;
exception when no_data_found then return false;
end;
$BODY$;
```

And this is the transaction in which the second select statement fails

```
begin;
select * from auth.authorize(uuid('180e1b14-21e5-4e66-a9b8-db09139d6278'));
select current_setting('auth.tenant_id') as tenant_id, current_setting('auth.user_role') as user_role;
commit;
```

Comment: A variation of this works for me. The simplest explanation is your query is not returning anything from `auth.authorizations` and `perform set_config('auth.tenant_id', v_tenant_id::text, true);` never happens.  What happens if you run: `select * from auth.authorize(uuid('180e1b14-21e5-4e66-a9b8-db09139d6278'));` by itself? Does it return `true` or `false`?

Comment: That works for me, strange.

Comment: If I change the `is_local` to `false` in `set_config` then it works, so generally the function works, but I only want the variables to exist during the transaction - so maybe I have some fundamental misunderstanding of postgres transactions?

Comment: Hmm. Postgres version? What does `select * from auth.authorize(...)` return when run by itself? Also in your function do something like: `select into _tenant_id current_setting('auth.tenant_id')` where `_tenant_id` is set up in the `DECLARE` portion and then `RAISE NOTICE 'tenant_id is %', _tentant_id;`. Just to see if it is actually set in the function.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks, you got me into the right direction. Adding `RAISE NOTICE` helped to ensure the function does the right thing. Next I realized that the pgAdmin Query Tool actually starts its own transaction, which was why I got some weird results. So now I just have to run it outside of the Query Tool and it seems to work. Still need to do some more testing, but will close this issue once this is done. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I do all my initial work in `psql`. If it fails there then I know I have a problem. Otherwise failures when moving up to other clients is a client issue, generally the client being 'helpful'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect of `set_config(is_local => true)` seems to be restrained to the implicit subtransaction created by your `BEGIN … EXCEPTION` block.

(Skip to the end of my answer for my TL;DR solution to your problem.)

Here's what happens when I do something similar, but with the call to `set_config()` outside of the `BEGIN … EXCEPTION` subtransaction:

```sql
create or replace function set_config_outside_of_begin_except_block(denominator int)
    returns bool
    language 'plpgsql'
as $body$
begin
    perform set_config('my.setting', 'set before subtransaction', true);

    begin
        perform 10 / denominator;
        return true;
    exception when division_by_zero then
        return false;
    end;
end;
$body$;

begin
select current_setting('my.setting') as my_setting;
select set_config_outside_of_begin_except_block(1);
rollback;
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION
BEGIN
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "my.setting"
 set_config_outside_of_begin_except_block
------------------------------------------
 t
(1 row)

        my_setting
---------------------------
 set before subtransaction
(1 row)

ROLLBACK
```

Having moved the `set_config()` call to before the `BEGIN … EXCEPTION` block, the new setting for `my.setting` has persisted outside our function call.

And, as you will next see, it doesn't even matter if an exception occurs in the above `BEGIN … EXCEPTION` block, which makes sense, given that the `set_config()` is called *before* that block/subtransaction is entered:

```sql
begin
select current_setting('my.setting') as my_setting;
rollback;
```

```
BEGIN
 set_config_outside_of_begin_except_block
------------------------------------------
 f
(1 row)
        my_setting

---------------------------
 set before subtransaction
(1 row)

ROLLBACK
```

Now, I will modify the code a bit to come closer to your example, and closer to reproducing the behavior you describe:

```sql
create or replace function set_config_in_begin_except_block(denominator int)
    returns bool
    language 'plpgsql'
as $body$
begin
    perform set_config('my.setting', 'set in subtransaction', true);
    perform 10 / denominator;
    return true;
exception when division_by_zero then
    return false;
end;
$body$;

begin;
select set_config_in_begin_except_block(0);
select current_setting('my.setting') as my_setting;
rollback;
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION
BEGIN
 set_config_in_begin_except_block
----------------------------------
 f
(1 row)

 my_setting
------------

(1 row)

ROLLBACK
```

```sql
begin
select set_config_in_begin_except_block(1);
select current_setting('my.setting') as my_setting;
rollback;
```

```
BEGIN
 set_config_in_begin_except_block
----------------------------------
 t
(1 row)

      my_setting
-----------------------
 set in subtransaction
(1 row)

ROLLBACK
```

Note that, now,

1. the `BEGIN … EXCEPTION` block does cause the change to `my.setting` to get lost,
2. but only if an exception (`division_by_zero`) indeed got raised,
3. even though the `division_by_zero` was triggered by the statement *after* `set_config()`.

So, it's somewhat close to the behaviour you describe, but not quite. Your setting didn't persist outside of your `BEGIN … EXCEPTION` block *regardless* of whether a `no_data_found` exception was hit or not.

As a little detour: I stumbled upon your question, because I was interested in whether I could treat the settings like a stack that unwinds together with the (sub)transaction stack. It turns out that I could:

```sql
create or replace function set_config_stacked(denominator int)
    returns bool
    language 'plpgsql'
as $body$
begin
    perform set_config('my.setting', 'set before substraction', true);

    begin
        perform set_config('my.setting', 'set within subtransaction before division', true);
        perform 10 / denominator;
        return true;
    exception when division_by_zero then
        return false;
    end;
end;
$body$;

begin;
select set_config_stacked(1);
select current_setting('my.setting') as my_setting;
rollback;
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION
BEGIN
 set_config_stacked
--------------------
 t
(1 row)

                my_setting
-------------------------------------------
 set within subtransaction before division
(1 row)

ROLLBACK
```

```sql
begin;
select set_config_stacked(0);
select current_setting('my.setting') as my_setting;
rollback;
```

```
BEGIN
 set_config_stacked
--------------------
 f
(1 row)

       my_setting
-------------------------
 set before substraction
(1 row)

ROLLBACK
```

So `my.setting` is actually restored to its previous setting when the subtransaction of the `BEGIN … EXCEPTION` block closes.

I need one final change to reproduce your function's behaviour:

```sql
create table tab (id uuid primary key, stuff text);
insert into tab (id, stuff) values (uuid('180e1b14-21e5-4e66-a9b8-db09139d6278'), 'some stuff');

create or replace function set_config_stacked(id$ uuid)
    returns bool
    language 'plpgsql'
as $body$
declare
    rec tab%rowtype;
begin
    perform set_config('my.setting', 'set before substraction', true);

    begin
        perform set_config('my.setting', 'set within subtransaction before SELECT', true);
        select * into strict rec from tab where id = id$;
        perform set_config('my.setting', 'set within subtransaction after SELECT', true);
        return true;
    exception when no_data_found then
        return false;
    end;
end;
$body$;

begin;
select set_config_stacked(uuid('180e1b14-21e5-4e66-a9b8-db09139d6278'));  -- exist
select current_setting('my.setting') as my_setting;
rollback;
```

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 1 0
CREATE FUNCTION
 set_config_stacked
--------------------
 t
(1 row)

               my_setting
----------------------------------------
 set within subtransaction after SELECT
(1 row)

ROLLBACK
```

```sql
begin;
select set_config_stacked(uuid('cc7ad0c3-7e3a-49a0-b7d8-7b4093ae0028'));  -- doesn't exist
select current_setting('my.setting') as my_setting;
rollback;
```

```
BEGIN
 set_config_stacked
--------------------
 f
(1 row)

       my_setting
-------------------------
 set before substraction
(1 row)

ROLLBACK
```

As you can see, there is still one aspect of the behavior that you describe which I cannot reproduce. This version of `set_config_stacked()` that operates around a `no_data_found` exception behaves the same as the previous version based around the `division_by_zero` exception.

However, your example suggests that your settings also don't persist outside of `auth.authorize()` when *no* exception is hit. That confounds me, and is not something I am able to reproduce, at least here on Postgres 14.

Regardless of this, your problem can be solved by moving the calls to `set_config()` below the `BEGIN … EXCEPTION … END` block. You will still want to set your variables *within* that block, but do these calls and the `return true` from a new to be created outer `BEGIN … END` block (without `EXCEPTION`).